# Validation password doesn't work in p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 4.0 and I'm trying to use a dialog to change password.
I used password component to do this job It does n't work in a dialog but It works fine when I'm not using Dialog.

Here is my code

```
<h:form>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="changePw" resizable="true" appendTo="@(body)"
              modal="true" closable="false" id="changePw">

        <p:panel header="change password">

            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" showSummary="false"
                        autoUpdate="true" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid">
                <h:outputLabel for="pwdNew" value="New: *" />
                <p:password id="pwdNew" value="#{passwordBean.newPw}" feedback="true"
                            match="pwdConf" required="true"
                            validatorMessage="Pw does n't matches"
                            requiredMessage="Value required">
                </p:password>

                <p:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="false" autoUpdate="true"
                            for="pwdNew" />

                <h:outputLabel for="pwdConf" value="Confirm Password: *" />
                <p:password id="pwdConf" value="#{passwordBean.newPwConfirmation}"
                            feedback="true" required="true"
                            validatorMessage="invalid password"
                            requiredMessage="Value required">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{8,60}" />
                </p:password>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

        <p:separator></p:separator>
        <p:commandButton value="Save" update="matchGrid"
                         process="@this" ajax="true"
                         actionListener="#{passwordBean.changePw}"
                         styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
                         oncomplete="changePw.hide();"
                         icon="ui-icon-check" />

        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" process="@this"
                         onclick="changePw.hide();" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
                         icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </p:dialog>

    ...
```

Thank for any suggestion !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a 'appendTo="@(body)"', you need a form IN the dialog as can be read in the [PrimeFaces documentation](https://speakerdeck.com/player/827b32202f6f01321c076e02156363ec?slide=176#). But make sure that it is in the original xhtml NOT nested!

In addition, the `process="@this"` on the buttons prevent the other inputs to be submitted (this also won't work outside the dialog, so you most likely did not have that there). So remove that as well

Comment: thank you for your answer I added a form in my dialog by I still have the same problem. I don't inderstand why it works fine outside a dialog

Comment: Make sure you *don't* have nested forms... (check if you also have an open/close form tag around your dialog *somewhere*)

Comment: The values do get submitted? Check browser logs/console/network etc... and also try to update your `messages` explicitly from the commandbuttons

Comment: The values are n't submitted and if I remove process="@this" the listener is not called

Comment: I missed the process="@this". Having that outside the dialog wil allso make if fail... If the listener is not called then there could be validation errors or whatever... Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked/

Comment: adding a form in the dialog and removing process="@this" solved the problem thanks